# OpenCV / Tesseract: How to replace libpng, libtiff etc with GDI+ Bitmap (Load into cv::Mat via GDI+)

Tags: c++, opencv, unicode, gdi+, libpng

I'm working on a project that uses OpenCV and Tesseract. Both libraries are based on 
libpng, libtiff, libjpeg, etc.. to load/save image files.

But Tesseract (based on Leptonica) uses older versions of these libraries which have incompatible parameters. So I cannot use the same image libraries for both: OpenCV an Tesseract.

So if I compile my project dynamically, I will have to deliver a bunch of DLLs with my project.
And if I compile statically I produce a huge output file blown up by several megabytes.

This is UGLY. I don't want that.

Another problem is that nearly all open source projects - mainly developed in Linux/MAC world - do not support Unicode if compiled on Windows. Internally they all pass a `std::string` to `fopen()`. On Linux the workaround to encode the path with UTF8 may function, but on Windows it will not. So a Japanese user cannot open an image file in a folder with a Japanese name. While Microsoft already in the early 1990's made big efforts to convert the entire Windows NT operating system to be 100% Unicode compatible, the majority of open source projects (like libpng) 20 years later still does not support passing a path via `std::wstring`.

**IMPORTANT**: The OpenCV commands `imread()` and `imwrite()` must NOT be used on Windows if you want to create an international project with support for Japanese or Chinese!

So, what I want is:
Eliminate libtiff, libpng, libjpeg, etc completely from my project:

In OpenCV comment out:

```
// #define HAVE_JASPER
// #define HAVE_JPEG
// #define HAVE_PNG
// #define HAVE_TIFF
etc..
```

In Tesseract / Leptonica:

```
#define  HAVE_LIBJPEG   0
#define  HAVE_LIBTIFF   0
#define  HAVE_LIBPNG    0
#define  HAVE_LIBZ      0
#define  HAVE_LIBGIF    0
#define  HAVE_LIBUNGIF  0
etc..
```

..and use GDI+ instead that is part of the Windows operating system and that supports loading/saving BMP, TIF, PNG, JPG, GIF. Additionally GDI+ is Unicode compatible.

I know that this can be done with a few lines of code, but such a usefull class is missing in the OpenCV project. My first trials showed that this is not as trivial as it seems on the first look because a lot of conversions have to be done.

Is there a class that is already made for that purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could not find a ready class so I wrote my own:

I hope it will be useful for someone and I hope it will be included into the OpenCV project as an optional Add-On for Windows users.

Advantages:

1. Getting rid of several libraries that are already implemented into Windows,
2. Unicode support,
3. The Bitmap can be passed directly to C# applications.

When you study the code you will see that there are several pitfalls and that the conversion between `cv::Mat` and `Gdiplus::Bitmap` is not as trivial as it might seem.

**NOTE:** This code supports black/white (2 bit), gray scale palette (8 bit), 24 bit RGB and 32 bit ARGB images. Color palette images are not supported. But this does not matter as OpenCV doesn't support them neither and .NET also has a very limited support for them.

**HEADER FILE:**

```
#pragma once

#include <gdiplus.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "gdiplus.lib")

// IMPORTANT:
// This must be included AFTER gdiplus !!
// (OpenCV #undefine's min(), max())
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;

class CGdiPlus
{
public:
    static void  Init();
    static Mat  ImgRead(const WCHAR* u16_File);
    static void ImgWrite(Mat i_Mat, const WCHAR* u16_File);
    static Mat  CopyBmpToMat(Gdiplus::Bitmap* pi_Bmp);
    static Mat  CopyBmpDataToMat(Gdiplus::BitmapData* pi_Data);
    static Gdiplus::Bitmap* CopyMatToBmp(Mat& i_Mat);

private:
    static CLSID GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* u16_File);

    static BOOL mb_InitDone;
};
```

**CPP FILE:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CGdiPlus.h"

using namespace Gdiplus;

BOOL CGdiPlus::mb_InitDone = FALSE;

// Do not call this function in the DLL loader lock!
void CGdiPlus::Init()
{
    if (mb_InitDone)
        return;

    GdiplusStartupInput k_Input;
    ULONG_PTR u32_Token;
    if (Ok != GdiplusStartup(&u32_Token, &k_Input, NULL))
        throw L"Error initializing GDI+";

    mb_InitDone = TRUE;
}

Mat CGdiPlus::CopyBmpToMat(Bitmap* pi_Bmp)
{
    assert(mb_InitDone);

    BitmapData i_Data;
    Gdiplus::Rect k_Rect(0, 0, pi_Bmp->GetWidth(), pi_Bmp->GetHeight());
    if (Ok != pi_Bmp->LockBits(&k_Rect, ImageLockModeRead, pi_Bmp->GetPixelFormat(), &i_Data))
        throw L"Error locking Bitmap.";

    Mat i_Mat = CopyBmpDataToMat(&i_Data);

    pi_Bmp->UnlockBits(&i_Data);
    return i_Mat;
}

Mat CGdiPlus::CopyBmpDataToMat(BitmapData* pi_Data)
{
    assert(mb_InitDone);

    int s32_CvType;
    switch (pi_Data->PixelFormat)
    {
        case PixelFormat1bppIndexed:
        case PixelFormat8bppIndexed:
            // Special case treated separately below
            break;

        case PixelFormat24bppRGB:  // 24 bit
            s32_CvType = CV_8UC3; 
            break;

        case PixelFormat32bppRGB:  // 32 bit
        case PixelFormat32bppARGB: // 32 bit + Alpha channel    
            s32_CvType = CV_8UC4; 
            break; 

        default: 
            throw L"Image format not supported.";
    }

    Mat i_Mat;
    if (pi_Data->PixelFormat == PixelFormat1bppIndexed) // 1 bit (special case)
    {
        i_Mat = Mat(pi_Data->Height, pi_Data->Width, CV_8UC1);

        for (UINT Y=0; Y<pi_Data->Height; Y++)
        {
            BYTE* pu8_Src = (BYTE*)pi_Data->Scan0 + Y * pi_Data->Stride;
            BYTE* pu8_Dst = i_Mat.ptr<BYTE>(Y);

            BYTE u8_Mask = 0x80;
            for (UINT X=0; X<pi_Data->Width; X++)
            {
                pu8_Dst[0] = (pu8_Src[0] & u8_Mask) ? 255 : 0;
                pu8_Dst++;

                u8_Mask >>= 1;
                if (u8_Mask == 0)
                {
                    pu8_Src++;
                    u8_Mask = 0x80;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (pi_Data->PixelFormat == PixelFormat8bppIndexed) // 8 bit gray scale palette (special case)
    {
        i_Mat = Mat(pi_Data->Height, pi_Data->Width, CV_8UC1);

        BYTE* u8_Src = (BYTE*)pi_Data->Scan0;
        BYTE* u8_Dst = i_Mat.data;

        for (UINT R=0; R<pi_Data->Height; R++)
        {
            memcpy(u8_Dst, u8_Src, pi_Data->Width);
            u8_Src += pi_Data->Stride;
            u8_Dst += i_Mat.step;
        }
    }
    else // 24 Bit / 32 Bit
    {
        // Create a Mat pointing to external memory
        Mat i_Ext(pi_Data->Height, pi_Data->Width, s32_CvType, pi_Data->Scan0, pi_Data->Stride);

        // Create a Mat with own memory
        i_Ext.copyTo(i_Mat);
    }
    return i_Mat;
}

Bitmap* CGdiPlus::CopyMatToBmp(Mat& i_Mat)
{
    assert(mb_InitDone);

    PixelFormat e_Format;
    switch (i_Mat.channels())
    {
        case 1: e_Format = PixelFormat8bppIndexed; break;
        case 3: e_Format = PixelFormat24bppRGB;    break;
        case 4: e_Format = PixelFormat32bppARGB;   break;
        default: throw L"Image format not supported.";
    }

    // Create Bitmap with own memory
    Bitmap* pi_Bmp = new Bitmap(i_Mat.cols, i_Mat.rows, e_Format);

    BitmapData i_Data;
    Gdiplus::Rect k_Rect(0, 0, i_Mat.cols, i_Mat.rows);
    if (Ok != pi_Bmp->LockBits(&k_Rect, ImageLockModeWrite, e_Format, &i_Data))
    {
        delete pi_Bmp;
        throw L"Error locking Bitmap.";
    }

    if (i_Mat.elemSize1() == 1) // 1 Byte per channel (8 bit gray scale palette)
    {
        BYTE* u8_Src = i_Mat.data;
        BYTE* u8_Dst = (BYTE*)i_Data.Scan0;

        int s32_RowLen = i_Mat.cols * i_Mat.channels(); // != i_Mat.step !!

        // The Windows Bitmap format requires all rows to be DWORD aligned (always!)
        // while OpenCV by default stores bitmap data sequentially.
        for (int R=0; R<i_Mat.rows; R++)
        {
            memcpy(u8_Dst, u8_Src, s32_RowLen);
            u8_Src += i_Mat.step;    // step may be e.g 3729
            u8_Dst += i_Data.Stride; // while Stride is 3732
        }
    }
    else // i_Mat may contain e.g. float data (CV_32F -> 4 Bytes per pixel grayscale)
    {
        int s32_Type;
        switch (i_Mat.channels())
        {
            case 1: s32_Type = CV_8UC1; break;
            case 3: s32_Type = CV_8UC3; break;
            default: throw L"Image format not supported.";
        }

        CvMat i_Dst;
        cvInitMatHeader(&i_Dst, i_Mat.rows, i_Mat.cols, s32_Type, i_Data.Scan0, i_Data.Stride);

        CvMat i_Img = i_Mat;
        cvConvertImage(&i_Img, &i_Dst, 0);
    }

    pi_Bmp->UnlockBits(&i_Data);

    // Add the grayscale palette if required.
    if (e_Format == PixelFormat8bppIndexed)
    {
        CByteArray i_Arr;
        i_Arr.SetSize(sizeof(ColorPalette) + 256 * sizeof(ARGB));
        ColorPalette* pk_Palette = (ColorPalette*)i_Arr.GetData();

        pk_Palette->Count = 256;
        pk_Palette->Flags = PaletteFlagsGrayScale;

        ARGB* pk_Color = &pk_Palette->Entries[0];
        for (int i=0; i<256; i++)
        {
            pk_Color[i] = Color::MakeARGB(255, i, i, i);
        }

        if (Ok != pi_Bmp->SetPalette(pk_Palette))
        {
            delete pi_Bmp;
            throw L"Error setting grayscale palette.";
        }
    }
    return pi_Bmp;
}

Mat CGdiPlus::ImgRead(const WCHAR* u16_File)
{
    assert(mb_InitDone);

    Bitmap i_Bmp(u16_File);
    if (!i_Bmp.GetWidth() || !i_Bmp.GetHeight())
        throw L"Error loading image from file.";

    return CopyBmpToMat(&i_Bmp);
}

void CGdiPlus::ImgWrite(Mat i_Mat, const WCHAR* u16_File)
{
    assert(mb_InitDone);

    CLSID k_Clsid = GetEncoderClsid(u16_File);

    Bitmap* pi_Bmp = CopyMatToBmp(i_Mat);

    Status e_Status = pi_Bmp->Save(u16_File, &k_Clsid);

    delete pi_Bmp;

    if (e_Status != Ok)
        throw L"Error saving image to file.";
}

// Get the class identifier of the image encoder for the given file extension.
// e.g. {557CF406-1A04-11D3-9A73-0000F81EF32E}  for PNG images
CLSID CGdiPlus::GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* u16_File)
{
    assert(mb_InitDone);

    UINT u32_Encoders, u32_Size;
    if (Ok != GetImageEncodersSize(&u32_Encoders, &u32_Size))
        throw L"Error obtaining image encoders size";

    CByteArray i_Arr;
    i_Arr.SetSize(u32_Size);
    ImageCodecInfo* pi_Info = (ImageCodecInfo*)i_Arr.GetData();

    if (Ok != GetImageEncoders(u32_Encoders, u32_Size, pi_Info))
        throw L"Error obtaining image encoders";

    CStringW s_Ext = u16_File;
    int Pos = s_Ext.ReverseFind('.');
    if (Pos < 0)
        throw L"Invalid image filename.";

    // s_Ext = "*.TIF;"
    s_Ext = L"*" + s_Ext.Mid(Pos) + L";";
    s_Ext.MakeUpper();

    // Search the file extension
    for (UINT i=0; i<u32_Encoders; i++)
    {
        CStringW s_Extensions = pi_Info->FilenameExtension;
        s_Extensions += ';';

        // s_Extensions = "*.TIFF;*.TIF;"
        if (s_Extensions.Find(s_Ext) >= 0)
            return pi_Info->Clsid;

        pi_Info ++;
    }

    throw L"No image encoder found for file extension " + s_Ext;
}
```

Comment: Elmue how I could get in contact with you?

Comment: Click on my profile. There you find my website.